# How to enable wallet encryption from the command line?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind

Which command should I use to encrypt a previously unencrypted wallet from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command is: `bitcoin-cli encryptwallet mypassphrase`.

The list with all commands exposed through bitcoind's RPC API can be found here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list or can be fetched with the command: `bitcoin-cli help`.

It's worth noting that the `encryptwallet` command will not show up in `bitcoin-cli help`'s results once your wallet is encrypted, instead you will get three new commands: `walletlock`,
`walletpassphrase` and `walletpassphrasechange`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem was that I used "help" to see the list of the commands on another installation with encrypted wallet. So it didn't show me the this command.